# magit の log で --full-history を実行したい。

Tags: emacs

magit を使って log を表示する際に、 git の `--full-history` オプションを付与したいです。これはどうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Additional-proposed-infix-arguments-and-suffix-commands

に、任意のオプションを定義する方法が記述してあります。

`--full-history` であるならば、例えば次のように `init.el` に記述します。

```
(magit-define-popup-switch 'magit-log-popup
  ?F "Full History" "--full-history")
```